# Port restrictions and MACs

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, mac-address, ipv4

I have a question regarding connections within a university setting. In my room I have two network points. One for my **pc** and one for my **voip** phone. Each network port is restricted to one mac address, switches and hubs are blocked by security policies.

Is it possible to connect three devices using only the two existing ports, without the use of hubs, switches or routers? For example I would like to have two pcs and one voip phone.

Each device on the network must have it's mac address registered and is assigned an ip via dhcp.

I know it's possible to spoof mac addresses of registered devices on to non registered devices etc.

There is wifi available also however the signal isn't great and I would prefer a wired connection for stability/performance.

I appreciate the help and apologies if this is a silly question!

(note: I originally asked this on the etwork Engineering SE however I was advised to move it here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do this, but you're going to need to install Connectify, which you can get from http://connectify.me

Unfortunately, if you want unlimited hotspot uptime, you're going to also need at least the pro license, which is $21.00 for the lifetime. You'll need to go to connectify.me, then apply the coupon.

Once Connectify Hotspot is installed, you can set it up to do MAC scrambling, where it will make all traffic look like it's only coming from the one PC.

Comment: This looks interesting, but does that mean my 3rd device (pc) will be connected via wifi only? This isn't what I require, like I said I would prefer a wired connection for stability/performance. Thanks a lot for the suggestion though, I will definitely investigate!

Comment: what you'd do is setup the 'host' to share the ethernet port over wifi. There is about a 25% overhead, but that's it. BTW, you'd need to get Pro to customize the hotspots name, otherwise it'd look suspicious.